# What exactly is supposed to be the usage of [elements]?

Tags: discussion

[elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements) has [208 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements?sort=newest), of which [41 are currently closed](http://[elements]%20is:question%20closed:yes) (a whopping 20%!). The tag was created on Oct 2'14, and has **no tag usage as of yet.**

This has resulted in a varied application of the tag. Of the [167 open questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Belements%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ano), many could use alternate and well-defined tags:

- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42259/technecium-and-technetium?s=6%7C7.3274) could use [rare-earth-elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rare-earth-elements) instead
- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37053/what-is-difference-between-h-and-proton?s=12|7.3148) could use [ions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ions) instead
- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48806/naming-of-elements-113-115-117-and-118?s=15%7C7.0628) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6381/why-do-people-often-capitalize-element-names?s=11%7C7.3148) could use [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) instead
- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49226/is-copper-an-element-or-molecule?s=14%7C7.0628) could use [transition-elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition-elements) instead
- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/is-astatine-a-non-metal-or-a-metalloid?s=2%7C7.3796) could use [pnictogen](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pnictogen) instead

and there's many, many more.

**Though**, there are *some* ambiguous cases, that wouldn't make sense if [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements) was removed.

- [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-characteristic-colors-of-elements?s=10%7C7.3148) wouldn't make sense if only tagged [color](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)
- [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13908/something-denser-than-lead-but-with-lead-like-properties?s=1|7.3796) wouldn't make sense if only tagged [density](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density)
- [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/non-standard-source-of-lead?s=9%7C7.3274) simply doesn't seem to fit in any tags

So, definitely, the [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements) is being misused. And this meta post aims to find a solution for this tag.

---

*If you consider leaving a comment, consider leaving an answer instead so that others can vote on it and we can reach a conclusion. If there's already an answer supporting your view, consider voting on it instead.*

---

<sup>**Side-note:** this meta post is supposed to **reach a decision** regarding [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements), and in no way intends to be a **call-to-action** to start retagging all questions within the next 24 hours. This to decide the **what** and the **why** part, not the **when** part.</sup>

Comment: Imho homework needs to be taken care of first.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj As I said, this isn't a call to action post. I'm not saying we do this before or after [tag:homework]. In fact, I'm not talking about the time part at all...

Comment: Obviously: Water, fire, air, earth, and [Leeloo](https://g.co/kgs/rcFC4g).

Answer (score 1):

A **proposed solution** is going through all the questions and reevaluating their quality, whilst retagging them (do remove the [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements))

Questions that don't make much sense without the [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements) tag - like the three "ambiguous cases" above - are definitely in a minority and deserve a small community-wiki. We might find a pattern among them, that may require retagging them with another tag (new or old), or closure if they are bad quality, or decision on a case-by-case basis.

*Only* defining the tag usage for [elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements) wouldn't be a proper solution, because, while it may help tag future questions correcly, it wouldn't solve the current pile of questions tagged incorrectly.